# Hadoop cluster with ubuntu and Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hadoop, cluster-computing

I have three laptops(with ubuntu) that I am networking to act as a cluster for hadoop. I also have a windows only machine, is it possible to add that to the cluster and make it act as a node? Is it feasible? Has anyone come across such an issue?

Comment: Found this [link](http://hayesdavis.net/2008/06/14/running-hadoop-on-windows/) that shows how to install hadoop on windows with cygwin. A person has commented saying that he has set up a mix cluster with windows and linux machines. So it is possible I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have windows environment, I would suggest that you use VirtualBox and any Linux as Guest OS.

You can build your Hadoop cluster on that. There are numerous installation procedures available for Linux and you can't go wrong with that.

We are using it exactly this way for development purposes. Performance of Hadoop cluster is not a concern as is the functionality.

It also allows you to fine tune your `dev ops` since you can tear apart and start afresh with a new VM.

Easiest approach to build this way is to :

1. Install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)
2. Install [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/)
3. Use a community provided box from: http://www.vagrantbox.es/
4. Bootstrap your VM for yum packages
5. Move from NAT interface to Bridged Ethernet interface
6. Install Hadoop using SCM: http://www.cloudera.com/products-services/tools/
7. Bring up your cluster

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. On the ubuntu machines, Hadoop installation should be straightforward, you just need to follow the regular steps. Since Hadoop runs on Linux environment, you need to install Cygwin on your windows Machine which is a Linux-like environment for Windows, and will enable you to install and run Linux-based applications (like hadoop) on a Windows machine.

Here is the link for Cygwin Installation: http://www.cygwin.com/install.html